# Trying to insert into a linked list, but can't insert more than 2 values

Tags: java, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
public class SortedLinkedList implements SortedADT {

    private class ListNode {

        private Comparable object;
        private ListNode next;
    }
    private ListNode head;

    public String toString() {
        String listDetails = new String();
        if (this.head != null) {
            ListNode current = this.head;
            while (current != null) {
                listDetails += current.object + "\n";
                current = current.next;
            }
        } else {
            listDetails += "list is empty";
        }
        return listDetails;
    }

    public void insert(Comparable object) throws NotUniqueException {
        /* algorithm        
            create a new node //will create component object reference
            if list empty then
                add to head of list
            else
                set current node to head of list
                while insertion position not yet found loop
                    if object to be added matches current object then
                        // attempt to add duplicate object
                        throw not unique exception
                    end if
                    if object to be added is less than current object then
                        link the new node to the current node
                        if current node is the head then
                            // add to the front of the list
                            link the head to the new node
                        else
                            link the previous node to the new node
                        end if
                    else
                        if current node is the last in the list
                            // add at end
                            link the current node to the new node
                        else
                            // move to the next node
                            set the previous node as the current node
                            set the current node to the next node
                        end if
                    end if
                end loop
            end if              
         */
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
        newNode.object = object;
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            ListNode current = this.head;
            // require to explicitly set to null to avoid compilation error
            ListNode previous = null;
            Boolean insertionPositionFound = false;
            while (!insertionPositionFound) {
                if (object.compareTo(current.object) == 0) {
                    throw new NotUniqueException();
                }
                // add code here
                if (object.compareTo(current.object) < 0) {
                    newNode.next = current.next;

                    if (current.next == this.head) {
                        this.head = newNode;
                        insertionPositionFound = true;
                    } else {
                        previous = newNode;
                        insertionPositionFound = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (current.next == null) {
                        current.next = newNode;
                        insertionPositionFound = true;
                    } else {
                        previous = current.next;
                        current.next = this.head.next;
                        insertionPositionFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can insert two values, but after that, the outputted list never changes. I'm a bit wary that `insertionPositionFound = true;` shows up as an unused value, not sure why that is? Any pointers please? TIA

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

I'm really not sure what else to add? Sorry.

Edit: not sure if all of my `insertionPositionFound = true;` are valid?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through and see exactly what the code is doing and why you aren't getting more than 2 in the list.

Comment: @xtratic - OK, I'll try that tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: The reason it isn't working is that: in insert() you set `insertionPositionFound = true;` in every branch of the if statements so you never actually loop and you only check the first item in the list.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah - right, thanks. i wasn't getting anywhere with it, so I had to just look at the solution, in the end.

Comment: Do you understand why your original wasn't looping through the list?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah - yes, because setting `insertionPositionFound = true;` in every case stopped it from going any further. Thanks.